# Number of cores for an executable in Python

Tags: python, executable

I am using this executable to run 10 programs in sequence. How do I know if this uses a single core or all cores when running a program?

```
I=[i+1 for i in range(10)]
for i in I:
    try: 
        exec(open(rf"C:\Users\All_combined_Test3.py").read()) 
    except Exception as e: 
            print(f"Error in script {i}: {e}") 
    continue
```

Comment: You're running the contents of that file 10 times *in sequence*, as you said. As in, *not* in parallel.

Comment: So it uses a single core? Is there a way to run these programs in parallel using a similar executable?

Comment: A single Python process running Python code only uses one core, even if you use multithreading.  There is a global lock that ensures that.  If you want that code to run in parallel, you will have to start 10 different processes.  That can certainly be done, using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you please point me to a relevant resource so that I can parallelize the executable?

Comment: @TimRoberts Curious- Although the python threads are blocked by the GIL, couldn't they still be running on different cores when they get their turn? My understanding was that the threads spawned are real threads created by the OS, just limited by the GIL?

Comment: Is there a way to find out how many cores the executable uses?

Comment: if you are using CPython and `All_combined_Test3.py` is just regular Python code, then the interpreter process is behind the GIL (global interpreter lock) so it will only ever execute on one core.

Comment: The specific cores it uses are irrelevant.  It only uses one at a time.  A single process will shift from core to core as it runs.  A multithreaded (non-Python) app can certainly use multiple CPUs at a time.  Why do you want to know how many?  That question usually indicates a misunderstanding of scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Base on your code, you just use 1 core.
2. Only use 1 core without multiprocessing in Python.
3. You can use multiprocessing in your code, it could use all cores of CPU.
4. If you only need 10 cores, just try **pool** :

> ```
> from multiprocessing import Pool
> import os
> with Pool(os.cpu_count()) as p:
>     pass #do your executable
> ```